# How to use Facebook Javascript SDK to login and force re-authentication with React Web and Typescript inside of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, typescript, sdk

this is my first question on stack overflow so let me know If I can improve it.

Would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction here. I'm trying to log a user in to facebook and force them to authenticate their profile or pick another profile (rather than having facebook automatically logging them in).

I've already tried the react-facebook-login npm https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login but it didn't allow me to force users to authenticate, though it did work to log them in.

So I'm trying to use the Facebook Javascript SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart with a React + Typescript Web App to build a component that will log a user into facebook and force them to authenticate their profile.

Building off of this tutorial: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/facebook-authorization-in-a-react-app-b7a9176aacb6 and then trying to adjust it for typescript.

First I'm trying to connect to facebook in the componentDidMount method

```
componentDidMount() {
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        window.FB.init({
            appId: "<my-app-id>", // replaced this with my app id
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: "v3.1",
        });
        window.FB.Event.subscribe("auth.statusChange", (res: any) => {
            if (res.authResponse) {
                this.updateLoggedInState(res);
            } else {
                this.updateLoggedOutState();
            }
        }).bind(this);
        (function (d: any, s: any, id: any) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));
    };
}
```

Then I'd like to call a login function onClick of a button component

```
login() {
    window.FB.login(
        (response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
        },
        { auth_type: "reauthenticate" }
    );
}
```

I get the following typescript errors

> property "fbAsyncInit" does not exist on type window
>
> property "FB" does not exist on type window

I can get rid of the errors by modifying the lines with window to be (window as any), however when the login function is called I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'login' of undefined

meaning that window.FB is undefined.

How can I integrate the Facebook SDK with React and Typescript then have a user log in with forced re-authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue solved it by adding a global type for fbAsyncInit:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    fbAsyncInit: () => void;
  }
}
```